# Error is showing incase of equalsIgnoreCase

Tags: java, jsp

I wrote query for dropdown box for Vendor List with values("Full Time", "Part Time"), i.e., I wanted to add drop down box for vendor contract select list which has 2 values, `full time` and `part time`.
Here is my code:

```
<td><b>Vendor Contract<font color="red">*</font></b></td>
    <td>
        <select id="Vendor Contract" name="Vendor Contract" style="width: 155" >
        <option selected value="">-select-</option>
        <% 
        Iterator<String> viterator = VendorList.iterator();
        while(viterator.hasNext()){
        String selected = ""; 
        String Vendor = viterator.next();
        if(Vendor.equalsIgnoreCase(VendorList))
        selected = "Selected";
        %>
        <option <%=selected%> value="<%=Vendor%>"><%=Vendor%></option>
        <%}%>
        </select>
    </td>
```

I'm getting error as shown:

```
The method equalsignorecase string in the type string isn't applicable for the arguments(array list(string))
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your passing an `ArrayList` to `equalsIgnoreCase` method, which it takes a `String` type. so you can't compare `String` to List of `Strings`.

From your code i think you need to determine the selected element from the list, and your code can't do that, since you comparing the same values all the time.

What you need to do is to get another factor to depend on, like create a class contain the value of the vendor and another value if it was selected like:

```
class VendorItem {
    private String value;
    private boolean selected;

    // setters and getters.
}
```

then in your code should looks like

```
Iterator<VendorItem> viterator = vendorItems.iterator();

while(viterator.hasNext()) {

String selected = ""; 
VendorItem vendor = viterator.next();

if(vendor.isSelected()) {
    selected = "Selected";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Vendor.equalsIgnoreCase(VendorList))
```

The method `equalsIgnoreCase` receives a string. You are passing an `ArrayList`.

String can't be compared against a List of String's. Pass the string which you wanted to compare.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `.equalsIgnoreCase()` accepts param of `String` type and you are passing `List` of `String`. You must be intending to compare user selection with List instead. Side note, avoid using jsp scriplets, try JSTL core tag instead.